# Can’t set figcaption text as firstChild of figure

Tags: javascript, html

I can set the text of a figcaption if I access it by its ID (Line commented out in code below). However I can’t set it if I access the figcaption as firstChild of the figure. Why not?

```
<body>

<figure id="fig1">
    <figcaption id="figcap1">Camberley Mail</figcaption>
    <button type="button" id="thumb1" onclick="showBigImg (1);"></button>
    <p>Text to go with picture.</p>
</figure>

<script>
"use strict";
function showBigImg(figNum) {
//    let temp = document.getElementById("figcap" + figNum);
    let temp = document.getElementById("fig" + figNum).firstChild;
    temp.innerHTML = "some text";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild). The `firstChild` you're selecting is the whitespace text node.

Comment: Your right. firstChild only works if there are no line breaks, spaces or tabs between the tags.